# Error while trying to create a simple procedure with parameter - Expecting a identifier

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a error at `@Email` parameter:

> `@Email` is not valid at this position, expecting a identifier

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `ValidarLogin` (@Email VARCHAR(45), @Senha VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
AS
    SELECT ID, NOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO 
    FROM usuario 
    WHERE EMAIL = @Email AND SENHA = @Senha;
END
```

Comment: put it in quotes : '@Email'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing *user defined variables* and *procedures IN/OUT parameters*. The former start with an arobas (`@`), while the latter do not.

As arguments, a stored procedure expects *parameters*, not *user variables*.

Consider:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `ValidarLogin` (pEmail VARCHAR(45), pSenha VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN   
AS
    SELECT ID, NOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO 
    FROM usuario 
    WHERE EMAIL = pEmail AND SENHA = pSenha;
END
```

References:

- [MySQL `CREATE PROCEDURE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)
- [MySQL User defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)